# After updating composer i am getting Call to undefined function Illuminate\Encryption\openssl_cipher_iv_length()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I ran composer update and also i updated php version, Now i am getting below error msg on my every laravel project

```
Call to undefined function Illuminate\Encryption\openssl_cipher_iv_length()
```

I am using xampp.

**what i tried**

i reinstall my composer by running composer install but i got

```
[Composer\Exception\NoSslException]
```

i updated path environment variable to php.ini,But still getting this error
 what should i need to do ?

Comment: Please share more details, for example the full and exact error message containing a stacktrace. Updating Composer itself won't run anything in Laravel's namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to add a missing `php-openssl` package to your PHP installation.

Open the php.ini file in your xampp installation and change

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

to

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

- remove the semicolon

You might need to restart xampp/apache after this change.

Comment: Hello @Bas Matthee This is not working for me.. I thik something else happened to it